# Using PyQt4, although I disconnect a slot, it keeps triggering

Tags: python, pyqt4, signals-slots

I want to execute a function in a list of objects, and store the results.
My problem in the code below, is that although I try to disconnect all signals, functionC keeps triggering somehow continuously. (disconnect outputs False)

```
class object(...):
  def init(self):
    ...
    self.emit(SIGNAL('result(bool)', result)
    ...

class classA(...):
  def functionA(self):
    self.results=[]
    self.i=0
    self.object[...]=... # len(self.object)=n
    self.functionB()

  def functionB(self):
    self.connect(self.object[self.i], SIGNAL('result(bool)'), lambda bool: self.functionC(bool))
    self.object[self.i].init()

  def functionC(self, result):
    print self.disconnect(self.object[self.i], SIGNAL('result(bool)', lambda bool: self.functionC(bool)) # outputs False (why cannot I disconnect it?)
    self.i+=1
    self.results.append(result)
    if self.i==len(self.object):
      print "finish"
      self.i=0
      return
    self.functionB()
```

Anyone could imagine the problem? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure if your code is just an example or if you really are using lambda functions for your slot. If you are indeed using a lambda, the reason is most likely because the lambda functions are completely different objects between your connect and disconnect:

```
>>> fn1 = lambda bool: self.functionC(bool)
>>> fn2 = lambda bool: self.functionC(bool)
>>> print fn1, fn2
<function <lambda> at 0x1004a9320> <function <lambda> at 0x1004a9398>
>>> fn1 == fn2
False
>>> fn1 is fn2
False
```

If pyqt is storing the function references and looking for the one you specify to disconnect, it will report that its not connected. What you want to do is actually reference a persistant callback. Either store the lambda as a member attribute and reference the same one both times, or define it as a standard method or function.